# Results of a Views display as an array

Tags: 7, views

With Views in D6, I was able to get the results of a Views display as an array and work with it using php code embedded in a node.

For example, using this code snippet:

```
$view = views_get_view('view_name', 1);
$view->set_display('block_1');  
$view->preview();
$MyArray = $view->result;
```

This allowed me to get the results of the 'block_1' view display into the $MyArray array.

However, I'm trying to do the same thing in D7 and all I'm getting is a list of all the nodes in the view I'm calling, and not the results of the view display.

How do I get the results of a view display in code for D7??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it has been replaced by the [`views_get_view_result()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) function. It returns:

> An array containing an object for each view item.

e.g.

```
$result = views_get_view_result('view_name', 'block_1');
```

Comment: Yes, that worked!  The resulting array is a little bigger than I'd like but I was able to extract what I needed from it.  Thanks!

Comment: This returns the results of the first page if using a pager. Is there a way to get all the results (without any pagination limits)?